# How to map subdomain to a domain with CNAME?

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain, cname, propagation

I would like to point CNAME records for www.example.com to sub.example2.com. The hosting for example2.com is a shared hosting (cPanel without Addon domain feature).

So, what I did was to add a subdomain in the cPanel: sub.example2.com

I then added a CNAME record for www (and without www) of example.com to sub.example2.com

After propagation, www.example.com shows the default server page of the hosting instead of showing the sub domain contents. If I access this subdomain directly, it works fine.

Can somebody help me with these, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your intent correctly, you have to tell cPanel that you want to serve `www.example.com`, not the other thing. Either that, or create a third virtual host somewhere (anywhere) that would handle `www.example.com` by doing a HTTP redirect to `sub.example2.com`.

Note also that you can't have a CNAME record for example.com without www, because a domain record already has SOA and NS records, and CNAME can't be combined with anything else - it has to be an A record.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to know about what you're doing:

You can't use a CNAME in the zone apex

(so as in the example.com zone a record "@ IN CNAME example2.com")

Theoretically it is, but in reality too many (resolving) nameservers get confused.

Comment: hi, can you please it a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain So, RFC's tell it should or should'nt work; in reality equally unreliable. Same for DNAME. Both RR's are kind of stupid anyway; it keeps a resolver busy by not providing a real answer. Latest development is that PowerDNS questioned the DNS community this would need it's own RR type. I think that's what Amazon did (using private RR types): http://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/?tag=viglink27244-20#Zone_apex - anyway just FYI to be aware of possible problems.